# Evenly distribute text diagonally along the whole image in Gimp

Tags: gimp

How can I use the alignment and distribute tool in Gimp 2.10 to achieve something like this:

```
|-----------|
|  A        |
|     B     |
|        C  |
|-----------|
```

Where "B" is text that is the exact centre of the image, and A and C are the same distance from the edges of the image as well as the same distance from the letter B along the Y axis.

Answer (score 2):

No way with that tool AFAIK.

The [`arrange-layers` script](http://gimp-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml) will do that easily, for instance, with one `Spread vertically with outer spaces` and one `Spread horizontally with outer spaces`:

[image]

Note that the script works on layer boundaries so you may have to autocrop the text layers so that the boundaries are the tightest fit possible for their contents.